# jquery.html jquery is not working when loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

the situation : 
1-i has a template that i load from database by ajax
2-then put it to a div 
3-allow user to change the values then take the whole html by jquery

First Step

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("getFormTemplate", "FormTemplate")",
              data: "CenterID=" + CenterID,
            dataType: "json",
              success: function (response) {
                  if (response.Success == "true") {

                      $('#d_AdditionalInfo2').empty().append(response.Value.Content);
                       }}});
```

First step works and the html is rendered correctly

last step is the problem 
when i use

```
 var htmlContent = $('#d_AdditionalInfo2').html();
```

the value return the original html without user inputs

what is the problem

Comment: this is not the same case as the duplicate link the form is fully loaded and the user type data into the inputs inside the form

Comment: OK if duplicate what is the answer in my case did not understand the link